# Jaybird 3 and default codepage via properties

Tags: firebird, codepages, jaybird

I continue to dig (or play) with jaybird 3 and got known error "Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Connection rejected: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding). Please specify a connection character set (eg property charSet=utf-8) or consult the Jaybird documentation for more information."

So, please help me what I do wrong and what I must to do.

1. First try

   ```
   final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:firebirdsql:localhost/3050:g:\\Databases\\EMPLOYEE255.FDB?lc_ctype=utf8",
           "sysdba",
           "masterkey"
   );
   ```

   That works fine. But what if I do not want (or cant) change the connection string?
2. As I see in faq: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html I run my java application (from netbeans) with option

   ```
   -Dorg.firebirdsql.jdbc.defaultConnectionEncoding=NONE
   ```

but got same error. So ok. May be I do something wrong here in netbeans...

3. I try to use connection options via Properties. So. I change my code:

   ```
   public DataSource createDataSource(){
       final DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
       ds.setDriverClassName( "org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver" );
       ds.setUrl( getConnectionURL( )); //here no appended "?lc_type...."
       ds.setUsername( getLogin() );
       ds.setPassword( getPassword() );
       //from here--->
       Properties pr = new Properties();
       pr.setProperty("lc_ctype", "utf8");
       ds.setConnectionProperties(pr);
       //<---to here
       return ds;
   }
   ```

Run application - and got same error.... I can't pass "lc_ctype" from property? Or I did not understand something?

Comment: Which exact beta version are you using, or, if a snapshot, the build date? There was a bug with the system property, but that was fixed in beta 3.

Comment: As to the last item: which library+version are you using there.

Comment: I tested all these options and they all work with Jaybird 3 beta 3 (and the snapshot of the 26th of March) + spring-jdbc 4.3.7.RELEASE. Please provide the information I asked for in my previous comments.

Comment: I got from snapshot and now seems it's work...

Comment: But were you using the snapshot or beta 3 when it didn't work, or were you using Jaybird 3 beta 2 or earlier?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - As I remember it was beta2...